# Why is the "Know someone who can answer" not available for my own question

Tags: feature-request, twitter

It seems logical to me to call out on twitter if anyone can answer my question, but that is not available. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the "share" button?  It's at the bottom left of your post, and has an option to tweet about the question.

[image: Tweety-tweet]

Comment: Thanks. I was just confused because it is different than other questions.